# How to Manage capacity using Trello?

Tags: project-management, trello

We started to play with  Trello to manage our manufacturing process. Great tool and we want to keep using it. But we are missing one functionality .

We want every agent to log monthly capacity that will be reduced every day and to have some report that will show how much load we already assigned to this individual. (To be able to plan how much work we can take more and estimate when we can deliver new coming  order)

Is it possible to achieve somehow in Trello? We can install additional plugins if required. Or we should look at different options?

Comment: Questions about the general usage of **web applications** are off-topic for Stack Overflow. You may be able to get help on [WebApps.SE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Trello documentation, there are some available options for this case;

[Burndown for Trello](https://www.burndownfortrello.com/)

[Harvest Chrome Extentation](http://www.getharvest.com/trello)

[Hubstaff](https://hubstaff.com/trello_time_tracking)

[Timecamp Chrome Extantation](https://www.timecamp.com/)

[Reports for Trello](https://reportsfortrello.com/)

[Plus for Trello Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/plus-for-trello-time-trac/gjjpophepkbhejnglcmkdnncmaanojkf?hl=en)

For the whole list, you can visit [here](http://help.trello.com/article/941-time-tracking)